# My Colors are not waiting the time I'm giving them actually there not waiting at all instead their speed running my entire time system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't know where I went wrong here, I'm trying to make a random choice attack system, well kind of but instead it's not waiting and at all for anything but probably for the first wait time. The results I'm looking for is: wait for amount of seconds then pick a random attack  then change color and go back to original color then  repeat process

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BossMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // changes color
    public Color originalColor;
   

    public Transform spawnPoint;

    // weapons

    //choses a  Attackmove to do
    int AttackChoice;

    
    public float distanceStop;
    public float distanceR;
    /// changes the material of the boss 
    private Material mymaterial;

    //animator 
    public Animator anim;

    public float distance;
    public float distance3;
    // player 
    public Transform target;

    // how fast we are going
    public float speed = 4f;
    public float speedR;




    Rigidbody rig;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        anim = GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();
        
        
    }
    
    private void Update()
    {
        
        whento();
        StopFollowing();
        StartCoroutine(AttackChoices());

    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void followPlayer()
    {
        var step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(rig.transform.position, target.position, step);
        

    }
            
    IEnumerator  AttackChoices()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(15);
        AttackChoice = Random.Range(0, 4);
        

        if (AttackChoice == 1)
        {
            
            gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>().material.color = Color.white;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(15);
            gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>().material.color  = originalColor;
        }

        if (AttackChoice == 2)
        {
            
            gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>().material.color = Color.blue;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(15);
            gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>().material.color = originalColor;
        }
        if (AttackChoice == 3)
        {

            gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(15);
            gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>().material.color = originalColor;
        }

        if (AttackChoice == 4)
        {

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(15);
        }

    }
    void whento()
    {
        // follow player
        transform.LookAt(target);

        //raycast that shoots at player
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, distance))
        {
            if (hit.transform.CompareTag("Player"))
            {
                followPlayer();
                anim.SetFloat("Speed", 1, 0f, Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetFloat("Speed", 0, 0.1f, Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    void StopFollowing()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, distance3))
        {

            if (hit.transform.CompareTag("Player"))
            {
                distance = distanceStop;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            distance = distanceR;
        }
    }

        private void ChargeUpAndRealse()
        {
            anim.SetLayerWeight(anim.GetLayerIndex("ChargeLayer"), 1);
            anim.SetTrigger("Charge");
            anim.SetLayerWeight(anim.GetLayerIndex("ChargeLayer"), 0);
        }

    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing

```
StartCoroutine(AttackChoices());
```

**EVERY FRAME** within `Update` starting thousands of concurrent running routines. A Coroutine does **not** delay the code which is using `StartCoroutine`.

You rather need to

- make sure to run only one routine, wait for i to finish, then start the next one
- or simply use a `while` loop

Like e.g.

```
private void Start()
{
    rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    anim = GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();
    
    StartCoroutine(AttackChoices());
}

private void Update()
{
    whento();
    StopFollowing();
}


void followPlayer()
{
    var step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(rig.transform.position, target.position, step);
}
        
IEnumerator  AttackChoices()
{
    while(true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(15);
        AttackChoice = Random.Range(0, 4);

        .....
    }
}
```

instead of `true` you could of course also have a certain flag field you can disable when you want to terminate the routine

---

Then note that

```
Random.Range(0, 4);
```

will return one of `0, 1, 2, 3` as the upper bound is **exclusive** for the `int` overload!

---

In general for better performance you should cache things and use a `switch`:

```
IEnumerator  AttackChoices()
{
    var material = GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>().material;

    while(true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(15);

        AttackChoice = Random.Range(0, 4);
        
        switch(AttackChoice)
        {
            case 0:
                // within an IEnuerator you can yield another one
                // which will execute it and at the same time wait until it finishes
                yield return ColorAndReset(Color.white);
                break;

            case 1:
                yield return ColorAndReset(Color.blue);
                break;

            case 2:
                yield return ColorAndReset(Color.red);
                break;

            case 3:
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(15);
                break;
        }
    }
}

private static IEnumerator ColorAndReset(Material material, Color color)
{
    material.color = color;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(15);
    material.color = originalColor;
}
```

---

And a last general note: If you are dealing with `Rigidbody` (=> Physics) you do **not** want to do anything via `transform` directly but rather only go through the `Rigibody` component! See e.g.

- [`Rigibody.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-position.html) for getting
- [`Rigibody.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) or setting wihout jumping

Also you want to do things in `FixedUpdate` (the Physics frame) in order to not break / fight against the Physics engine resulting in undesired behavior and breaking collision detection

Little hint here: The rigidbody alternative to

```
transform.forward
```

would be e.g.

```
rb.rotation * Vector3.forward
```